# PHP Redirect on successful return xml string

Tags: php, jquery, xml, api, redirect

I'm certain this is probably a many times over duplicate question, so if someone can at least point me to the right answer... I'm fairly new to using php and jquery, so here goes.

I have a user submission form that accesses another company's api for data input. They just recently switched to a combination of jquery and active server pages... on successful submission the server returns the following xml string ( I do NOT know how to work with xml!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Success (411817)</string>
```

How do I code a function using either php or jquery to redirect to thankyou.php when it returns "SUCCESS" or to error.php if it fails? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can call:

```
header('Location: some-other-page.php');
```

In JavaScript, you can say:

```
window.location.href = '/some-other-page.php';
```

Comment: In the end it turns out I f00f'd up the target on my form, so the process wasn't finishing. But that is still useful information for the future. Thank you!